# read_excel (from readxl package) reads dates before 1899-12-30 as NA, how to workaround this?

Tags: r

I have a dataset of 130 soccer matches that date back to 1893.

When I import the dataset from Excel the dates from 1900 are as they should be in R (RStudio). But, the dates from before 1900 come in as NAs.

How can I fix it so all dates come from Excel in the correct format?

Or, how can I replace the NAs with the correct (18XX-MM-DD) dates?

This is the data as it appears in Excel:

```
    Home_Team, Away_Team, SUFC, SWFC, H,  A,  Score, Season, Date

Sheffield United, Sheffield Wednesday, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1–1, 1893/94, 1893-10-16

Sheffield United, Sheffield Wednesday, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1–0, 1894/95, 1895-01-12

Sheffield United, Sheffield Wednesday, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1–1, 1895/96, 1895-12-26

Sheffield United, Sheffield Wednesday, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2–0, 1896/97, 1896-12-26

Sheffield United, Sheffield Wednesday, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1–1, 1897/98, 1897-12-27

Sheffield United, Sheffield Wednesday, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2–1, 1898/99, 1898-12-26

Sheffield United, Sheffield Wednesday, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1–0, 1900/01, 1900-12-15

Sheffield United, Sheffield Wednesday, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3–0, 1901/02, 1902-03-01

Sheffield United, Sheffield Wednesday, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2–3, 1902/03, 1902-09-01

Sheffield United, Sheffield Wednesday, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1–1, 1903/04, 1903-12-12

Sheffield United, Sheffield Wednesday, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4–2, 1904/05, 1905-04-08

Sheffield United, Sheffield Wednesday, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0–2, 1905/06, 1905-10-21
```

This is the R code I apply to it:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

Sheff_derby_R <- read_excel("sheffield_derby/Sheff_derby_R.xlsx", 
                        col_types = c("text", "text", "text", 
                                      "text", "text", "text", "text", 
                                       "text", 
                                      "date", "text", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                      "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                      "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                      "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                      "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                      "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                      "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                      "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                      "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                      "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                      "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                      "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                      "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                      "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                      "numeric", "text"))
 View(Sheff_derby_R)
```

In R it comes out with the 18xx dates (the final column, not the 18xx/xx season col) replaced with NA. This is the head, first 12 lines:

```
    Home_Team Away_Team SUFC  SWFC  H     A     Score Season Date                
   <chr>     <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dttm>              
 1 Sheffiel~ Sheffiel~ 1     1     1     1     1 – 1 1893/~ NA                  
 2 Sheffiel~ Sheffiel~ 1     0     1     0     1 – 0 1894/~ NA                  
 3 Sheffiel~ Sheffiel~ 1     1     1     1     1 – 1 1895/~ NA                  
 4 Sheffiel~ Sheffiel~ 2     0     2     0     2 – 0 1896/~ NA                  
 5 Sheffiel~ Sheffiel~ 1     1     1     1     1 – 1 1897/~ NA                  
 6 Sheffiel~ Sheffiel~ 2     1     2     1     2 – 1 1898/~ NA                  
 7 Sheffiel~ Sheffiel~ 1     0     1     0     1 – 0 1900/~ 1900-12-15 00:00:00 
 8 Sheffiel~ Sheffiel~ 3     0     3     0     3 – 0 1901/~ 1902-03-01 00:00:00 
 9 Sheffiel~ Sheffiel~ 2     3     2     3     2 – 3 1902/~ 1902-09-01 00:00:00 
10 Sheffiel~ Sheffiel~ 1     1     1     1     1 – 1 1903/~ 1903-12-12 00:00:00 
11 Sheffiel~ Sheffiel~ 4     2     4     2     4 – 2 1904/~ 1905-04-08 00:00:00 
12 Sheffiel~ Sheffiel~ 0     2     0     2     0 – 2 1905/~ 1905-10-21 00:00:00
```

Comment: it really all depends on the format of the pre-1900 dates in Excel and what R code you are using to read in. Consider sharing your R code here and maybe posting a link to an example Excel doc on dropbox

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 
Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far. It will help to track the issue and get expert's help.

Comment: I added the data in to the question.

Comment: This might be a bug in `readxl`. As a workaround you might try exporting the `xlsx` as `csv` and then read it with `read_csv` from the `readr` package.

Comment: It seems likely to be happening while reading the date format via read_xlsx_. Have you tried importing it as text and transforming the column with 'as.Date'?

Comment: I think it is really a bug, dates before `1899-12-30` seem to be read as `NA`. There seems to be an original bug from Microsoft that the guys from `readxl` tried to handle: the date `1900-02-29`... But somehow the code might be messing with these other dates before `1899-12-30`...

Comment: I agree with @plant, export your relevant Excel data to a csv. I copied your data into Excel, and ran your code. *My* `Date` column was ALL NAs. I couldn't improve it even by converting the cells in Excel to type `Date`, nor by converting the data to a table.

Comment: I've opened an issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/547.

Comment: Is there a way to add the missing values? There are only 12 of them. I tried fix() and replace_na() but got errors both times.

Comment: I also tried over-writing the date col with a new vector but that failed too.

Comment: @Mr_Percy_Heat: Could you share your original file? I'd like to make a few tests.

Comment: Google drive link >>> https://drive.google.com/open?id=17xBPOupJ_Kp2OC7K8Ea-4SOFF3UKOadV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the bug, here's a possible (temporary) workaround:

First, read in as `"text"` to see one reason why R is choking a little. (I'm over-simplifying the `read_excel` arguments here, since `"text"` is what it defaults to for `Date` in this case. In your case, just update from `"date"` to `"text"` in your vector of `col_types`.)

```r
library(readxl)
x <- read_excel("Sheff_derby_SO.xlsx")
x$Date
#  [1] "1893-10-16" "1895-01-12" "1895-12-26" "1896-12-26" "1897-12-27"
#  [6] "1898-12-26" "350"        "791"        "975"        "1442"      
# [11] "1925"
```

For dates 1900 and later, they are being passed as integers. They all happen to be based on the same date-origin, so as a hack we can do:

```r
wrong <- !grepl("-", x$Date)
as.Date("1900-01-01") + as.integer(x$Date[wrong]) - 2L
# [1] "1900-12-15" "1902-03-01" "1902-09-01" "1903-12-12" "1905-04-08"
```

which matches what excel tells me it *thinks* they should be.

N.B.: I expected it to be a simple offset, but the `+ 2L` was required to make it align. This suggests there might be something else going on, so *please* verify with all of your data (in case this is not all of it) that this hack holds true for other values.

[image: excerpt of excel spreadsheet showing "Date" column]

Replacing them in your dataset is as simple as

```r
sav <- as.Date("1900-01-01") + as.integer(x$Date[wrong]) - 2L
x$Date <- as.Date(x$Date) # 'wrong' ones will be NA
x$Date[wrong] <- sav
x$Date
#  [1] "1893-10-16" "1895-01-12" "1895-12-26" "1896-12-26" "1897-12-27"
#  [6] "1898-12-26" "1900-12-15" "1902-03-01" "1902-09-01" "1903-12-12"
# [11] "1905-04-08"
```