# Replace date NAs in tibble

Tags: r, readxl

I have an issue with dates not being read properly from `readxl` ([see thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54502851/read-excel-from-readxl-package-reads-dates-before-1899-12-30-as-na-how-to-wor?noredirect=1#comment95816082_54502851))

In the absence of a solution, how do I replace the NAs in the date column with manually keyed-in dates?

There are only 12 of them. I tried `fix()` and `replace_na()` but got errors both times.

I also tried over-writing the date column with a new vector but that failed too.

I tried:

```
df[is.na(df$Date),] <- keyed_in_dates_in_the_right_order
```

This was the code:

```
Sheff_derby_R[is.na(Sheff_derby_R$Date)] <- c("1893-10-16 UTC”, "1895-12-01 UTC”, 
    "1895-12-26 UTC”, "1896-12-26 UTC”, “1897-12-27 UTC”, "1898-12-26 UTC”, 
    "1893-11-13 UTC”, "1894-10-27 UTC”, "1896-09-07 UTC”, "1897-03-02 UTC”, 
    "1897-10-16 UTC”, "1898-10-03 UTC”)
```

It replaced everything in the first six rows with these dates recycled.

UPDATE: I got the required result by fixing the curly quotes issues and replacing the entire $Date column with all the correct dates. Not a great solution but it worked.IE:

```
df$Date <- c("1893-10-16 UTC" etc)
```

Comment: First i would try to save the excel-file as some sort of csv-file and try to read it to R with read.table or datatables fread. If this doesn't work you can select the missing values with your_data$date_variable[which(is.na(your_data$date_variable))] and assigne the dates you wish (the vector has to be as long as the number of missing values). lets say there are 3 missing values you could use your_data[which(is.na(your_data$date_variable))] = c("1.1.2010", "1.2.2011", "1.3.2012") - be careful with the ordering here.

Comment: It looks like you've got 2 types of quotation marks. This happens sometimes with reading files between operating systems, or from things like Excel. I'm not sure if what you've got here is code you pasted in from somewhere else. But look closely at the error message: `"1893-10-16 UTC”` One is a regular `"`, the other is angled "smart" quotes. So this is essentially a typo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the problem, it is in your quotation marks - just like camille commented.

If you look closely, you will notice that some of them are curly at the end while others are not. Change this such that all the dates that are entered share the same 'straight' quotes, where the vector replacing the `na` values should look like this:

If df is your dataframe

```
df[is.na(df$Date),] <- c("1893-10-16 UTC", "1895-12-01 UTC", 
"1895-12-26 UTC", "1896-12-26 UTC", "1896-09-07 UTC") #Or whatever combination of dates you wish to use
```

Worked with me so should work with you too!

Comment: This is the exact same code that the OP included that didn't work for them.

Comment: That is not true, camille. The post was edited after my answer was given. If that is why I was downvoted then maybe you should cancel it. Thanks

Comment: It's true. I edited after you gave your answer. I then fixed the typo and the code ran. However, it replaced every col in the first 6 rows with the recycled dates.

Comment: I got the required result by replacing the entire $Date column with all the correct dates. Not a great solution but it worked.IE, df$Date <- c("1893-10-16 UTC",